# Youtube Data API v3 for retrieving user likes is limited

Tags: youtube-api

I'm messing around with the API and have specified that I want 50 videos per response and have passed in a nextPageToken so I can get to the very end of my liked playlists

```py
response = youtube.videos().list(
            part="snippet",
            maxResults=50,
            myRating="like",
            pageToken=next_page
        ).execute()
```

I am able to get 969 videos but the responses stop giving back a nextPageToken so I am unable to retrieve the remaining liked videos for my account.

This cap is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation and I am unsure of why this is happening. Can someone shed some light?

Comment: *I am unable to retrieve the remaining liked videos*, is there a YouTube UI webpage to verify that you haven't retrieved all the liked videos? If so, which one?

Comment: Here is my likes page displaying 1,929 liked videos
https://ibb.co/xgLpNHX

Comment: [There are inconsistency with the YouTube UI due to the deleted videos](https://discord.com/channels/933841502155706418/933841503103627316/1162955210877042772), otherwise [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B"part"%3A%5B"snippet%2CcontentDetails"%5D%2C"maxResults"%3A25%2C"playlistId"%3A"LL"%7D) works.